# How do I get the number of selected options

Tags: javascript

I need some help.  I'm trying to get the length of the selected options in my elements with the "no" class(meaning getting the number of selected options with the no class name.  Copy and paste in browser to see what I am talking about and select the options yourself to see).

here is my html

```js
function Starting(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var artchoices = document.querySelectorAll(".art");
  var program = document.querySelectorAll(".program");
  var choice = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");
  var no = document.querySelectorAll(".no");
  var music = document.querySelectorAll(".music");
  var allchoices;

  for (var e = 0; e < choice.length; e++) {
    if (choice[e].selected == true) {
      allchoices = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (allchoices)
    console.log("Please make sure all options are selected");
  else {
    if (no.length.selected >= choice.length)
      console.log("hello");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="quiz" content="myown quiz">
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="machine.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizformatting.css">
  <h1>Choose the major right for you</h1>
  <pre>
    <form>
    Do you like enjoy programming?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="program">Yes</option>
    <option class="no">No</option>
    </select>
    
    
    Do you enjoy 2d animation and 3d animation?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="art">Yes</option>
    <option class="no">no</option>
    </select>
    
    
    Do you like music
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option class="no">no</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    What are your favorite pastimes?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Listening to music</option>
    <option>making websites</option>
    <option class="art">Drawing</option>
    <option class="no">None of these</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    
    Out of all the activities you like to do, which one do you enjoy the most?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="art">Painting and drawing</option>
    <option class="music">Playing instruments</option>
    <option class="art">Drawing</option>
    <option class="no">None of these</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    Would you be interested in making art or coding for video games?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="program">I would be interested in learning the programming 
    languages used to create the scripting for games</option>
    <option class="art">I would like to the models and the environment for 
     modeling</option>
    <option class="no">I'm not interested in either of these options</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    Do you enjoy making websites or learning how to sing?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Learning how to sing</option>
    <option class="program">making websites for projects</option>
    <option class="no">I'm not interested in any of this</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    
    Do you enjoy listening to music more or making programming applications?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">I would like to listen to music</option>
    <option class="program">Programming is my thing</option>
    <option class="art">I'm more of a drawer</option>
    <option class="no">I don't like any of these options</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    Which skillset are you more interested in learning?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Learning the notes of instruments</option>
    <option class="program">Learning the language of javascript</option>
    <option class="art">I like anime, so I would love to learn how to animate in 
    anime style</option>
    <option class="no">I don't want to do any of these options</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    Please press the button to get your answer
    
    <button onclick="Starting(event);">Click me</button>
    </form>
    </pre>
</body>

</html>




Here is my javascript file:
```

Comment: Instead of using a `class` for each of your options, you might consider using a `value` instead. Much easier to query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:checked` pseudo-class to find all of the option elements that are selected. In this case, I've changed the selector you've used in `querySelectorAll` so that `no` only has the selected options with the class "no".

As @PatrickRoberts mentions in the comments, using a `value` attribute is a better idea. For one thing it is semantically correct (`option`s should have a `value` for form submission).

```js
function Starting(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var artchoices = document.querySelectorAll(".art");
  var program = document.querySelectorAll(".program");
  var choice = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");
  var no = document.querySelectorAll(".no:checked");
  var music = document.querySelectorAll(".music");
  var allchoices;

  for (var e = 0; e < choice.length; e++) {
    if (choice[e].selected == true) {
      allchoices = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (allchoices)
    console.log("Please make sure all options are selected");
  else {
    if (no.length >= choice.length)
      console.log("hello");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="quiz" content="myown quiz">
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="machine.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizformatting.css">
  <h1>Choose the major right for you</h1>
  <pre>
    <form>
    Do you like enjoy programming?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="program">Yes</option>
    <option class="no">No</option>
    </select>
    
    
    Do you enjoy 2d animation and 3d animation?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="art">Yes</option>
    <option class="no">no</option>
    </select>
    
    
    Do you like music
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option class="no">no</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    What are your favorite pastimes?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Listening to music</option>
    <option>making websites</option>
    <option class="art">Drawing</option>
    <option class="no">None of these</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    
    Out of all the activities you like to do, which one do you enjoy the most?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="art">Painting and drawing</option>
    <option class="music">Playing instruments</option>
    <option class="art">Drawing</option>
    <option class="no">None of these</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    Would you be interested in making art or coding for video games?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="program">I would be interested in learning the programming 
    languages used to create the scripting for games</option>
    <option class="art">I would like to the models and the environment for 
     modeling</option>
    <option class="no">I'm not interested in either of these options</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    Do you enjoy making websites or learning how to sing?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Learning how to sing</option>
    <option class="program">making websites for projects</option>
    <option class="no">I'm not interested in any of this</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    
    Do you enjoy listening to music more or making programming applications?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">I would like to listen to music</option>
    <option class="program">Programming is my thing</option>
    <option class="art">I'm more of a drawer</option>
    <option class="no">I don't like any of these options</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    Which skillset are you more interested in learning?
    <select>
    <option class="choice">Select a value</option>
    <option class="music">Learning the notes of instruments</option>
    <option class="program">Learning the language of javascript</option>
    <option class="art">I like anime, so I would love to learn how to animate in 
    anime style</option>
    <option class="no">I don't want to do any of these options</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
    Please press the button to get your answer
    
    <button onclick="Starting(event);">Click me</button>
    </form>
    </pre>
</body>

</html>




Here is my javascript file:
```

Comment: Thanks Heretic Monkey

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to jQuery, you can use the following script:

`$('form option.no:selected').length`